# providing images in different resolutions for a universal app

Tags: ios

Apple says that all images that we are using should be available in two resolution - one for retina and one for non-retina device.

In my case, as i am building a universal app, i need to put four sets of images for each image - iPhone non-retina, iPhone retina, iPad-non retina, iPad-retina.

do i have to provide 4 sets of each and every image?? even for the images that i am directly using in xib (like background of a button). I am sure i need to do that for app icons, launch images, nav bar buttons etc..

Comment: I have made tons of universal apps and I used one set of image for both retina and non-retina screens. If your initial image is large it should work for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "have" to, no.  If you provide only one image the OS will do all the scaling of that image based on the sizes you want it shown and the current hardware capabilities.  Sometimes it's ok for a single image to be used on all devices, sometimes it's not.  You need to be the judge of that.  Just test it, look very closely at the image on the different devices.  If it looks nice enough to you then be satisfied and move to the next, if not then create new resolutions.